# Really Big Decimals

Tags: probability

Is there a probability that in a number such as e (2.7182818284590452353602874713527....) there will reach a point, no matter how long it takes (or how many blown-up processors), where mathematicians will start to notice a repeating pattern? It could be the $10^{10^{100^{100^{100}}}}$th digit, but do you think it's possible?

Comment: No, for $e$, because this is known to be irrational, and repeating decimals are always rational

Comment: Well, *some* mathematician will probably start to note a repeating pattern. They'll be wrong though.

Comment: $e$ is not rational, but it has short repeating patterns including the early  $18281828$

Comment: You might find this [amusing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_point).

Comment: Either 1. "repeating pattern" is understood strictly (fixed sized string of digits, repeating one after other) and then the answer is "no unless it's a rational number". Or  2. it's understood in some ample sense (so that, for example, the Liouville constant fits the bill), and then the statement is too vague to hope for a definite answer.

Comment: The rationals are countable, the reals uncountable. The chance of a random sequence being rational is zero.

Comment: @Bye_World based on what i read, you'll probably find a pattern in _e_...only for it to fall apart again. It's just like pareidolia - you will see a pattern, but it doesn't really mean anything because you could really perceive what you want to perceive. This number e.g., there are hundreds of 'patterns' in it, but there appears to be no 'meta-pattern' of any sort.

Comment: @Bye_World that is not what normal means.  It is a consequence of normality, but it could be true without $e$ being normal.